# How to access WordPress post admin data inside the loop?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to access some fields that have been assigned to a post via a plugin named Snax.

You can see here in the admin that "Story" has being assigned to a post as a "Snax Format":

[image]

But when I check the `$post` object inside the loop on the front end using something like `$my_post = get_post(); var_dump($my_post);` I can't see any anything relating to snax or "story".

What php can I use to access that post data on the front end inside the loop?

I'm asking because I want to use that field data inside my post template.

Comment: The Wordpress post object only contains the standard Wordpress information about the post (id, title, slug, date, etc). All other information added by plugins, themes etc is added as post meta, and is accessed by `get_post_meta()`. Some posts might have it, some might not - it all depends on the code in the theme/plugin that adds it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the plugin will store they data as meta_values. You can retrieve this data with [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

```
$meta_data = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );
var_dump( $meta_data );
```

Comment: Thanks, using this it seems that on some posts I can retrieve a key "_snax_format" which is what I need. But other times that key is missing entirely. Is there another more reliable solution?

Comment: As you can see in your Screenshot, some posts have Snax Format: Story, and some has no value. The posts without a value do not have this key '_snax_format'. Use `$value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_snax_format', true )` to check the value.

Comment: Yes but checking the posts that do have a format assigned, sometimes that key does not show. Using your updated code on such a post just returns an empty string. It has "Story" showing in admin, but it won't show that inside the loop when checking the meta data.